# Convert an array of JSON objects into a variable that can be used to make titles for Rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, formatting

I am taking an array of JSON encoded objects and trying to make each object the title of it's own row.

Currently the row gets it's name from a counter (1,2,3,etc.) as such

```
$.row.title = "Job " +counter;
```

So the rows display as

```
|Job1 |
|-----|
|Job 2|
|-----|
|Job 3|
```

the array responds with two parts to the title, title part 1 and title part two are the pieces needed. The array that is responding is:

```
 [{"ID":1,"titlepart1":"titlepart1words","titlepart2":"titlepart2word","userID":"1"},{"ID":2,"titlepart1":"titlepart1words","titlepart2":"titlepart2word","userID":"1"},{"ID":3,"titlepart1":"titlepart1words","titlepart2":"titlepart2word","userID":"1"}]
```

I need to take the information in the array and change it so that the Rows display title part 1 and title part 2

```
|ID1 titlepart1 +titlepart2|
|--------------------------|
|ID2 titlepart1 +titlepart2|
|--------------------------|
|ID3 titlepart1 +titlepart2|
```

Finally I do have control over how the PHP is sending the information to the Javascript. So if there are any recommendations on the PHP I can adjust that. Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be just loop over the array?

```
var obj =[{"ID":1,"titlepart1":"titlepart1words","titlepart2":"titlepart2word","userID":"1"},{"ID":2,"titlepart1":"titlepart1words","titlepart2":"titlepart2word","userID":"1"},{"ID":3,"titlepart1":"titlepart1words","titlepart2":"titlepart2word","userID":"1"}]

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    console.log(obj[i].ID + " " + obj[i].titlepart1 + obj[i].titlepart2);
}
```

Result:

```
1 titlepart1wordstitlepart2word
2 titlepart1wordstitlepart2word
3 titlepart1wordstitlepart2word
```